# Remove Layers/Background from PDF in PHP/Bash/C#

Tags: c#, php, pdf, imagemagick, gd

I have some PDF files that I need to modify using a PHP script. I'm also able to exec() so I can use pretty much anything that runs on CentOS.

The PDF files when opened through Adobe Acrobat Pro X, show 2 layers in the "layers" panel:

1. Background
2. Color

When I disable both of these layers I end up with a black & white text & images (the text is not vector tho, it's a scanned document).

I want to disable these layers and any other similar layer found in the PDFs using PHP and/or C# or any command-line tool.

Other useful information:

When I run pdfimages (provided with XPDF) on my PDFs, it extracts exactly what I actually need removed from each page...

Additional Information Update:
I modified the PDFSharp example here: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ExportImages-sample.ashx :

Modified:
Line 28: `ExportImage(xObject, ref imageCount);`

To:
`PdfObject obj = xObject.Elements.GetObject("/OC");`
`Console.WriteLine(obj);`

I got the following output in the console for each image:
`<< /Name Background /Type /OCG >>`
`<< /OCGs [ 2234 0 R ] /P /AllOff /Type /OCMD >>`
`<< /Name Text Color /Type /OCG >>`

Which is actually the layer information, and the PDFSharp Documentation for the /OC key:

> Before the image is processed, its
>   visibility is determined based on this
>   entry. If it is determined to be
>   invisible, the entire image is
>   skipped, as if there were no Do
>   operator to invoke it.

So now, how do I modify the /OC value to something that will make these layers invisible?

Comment: "so feel free to post a solution using any of them" This site unfortunately doesn't work like this. You need to actually make an attempt at the code yourself, show where you're confused, then we can try to provide some help. Otherwise there are plenty of freelance boards you can post to which can provide you such code for a fee, if the requirements are feasible.

Comment: I'm confused at the point where none of the PDF manipulation libraries and tools on the net have something like "extract layer information". I don't want a complete solution, I just want someone to point me to the right link or tool ability.

Comment: I imagine it would be quite tricky to do that, I can't say I've ever seen a command line tool, or library that can do that.  It's conceivable the code from `pdfimages` could be adapted to cut, rather than copy.

Comment: I'm currently looking at this code: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ExportImages-sample.ashx

Now let's see if it can remove the images from each page instead of exporting it, downloading now :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After long hours of experimenting, I found the way! I'm posting the code so someone may find it helpful in the future:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace LayerHide {

    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("test.pdf");
            PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream("test2.pdf", FileMode.Create));
            Dictionary<string, PdfLayer> layers = stamp.GetPdfLayers();

            foreach(KeyValuePair<string, PdfLayer> entry in layers )
            {
                PdfLayer layer = (PdfLayer)entry.Value;
                layer.On = false;
            }

            stamp.Close();
        }
    }
}
```